# Регулярное выражение для Regex

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Как прописать регулярное выражения для Regex , чтобы в строке найти два одинаковых слова(не более)?

Comment: давайте немного уточним вопрос (для редактирования под вопросом есть кнопка [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1056393/edit)). 1. Что такое слово в вашем случае/понимании? 2. Приведите пример строки, в которой нужно найти пару слов и выделите искомые слова, например жирным шрифтом (используйте `**текст**` или соответствующую кнопку редактора). Очевидно что одинаковых слов должно быть больше двух, судя по упоминанию условия "не более" 3. Если что-то пробовали самостоятельно, но не получилось, тоже стоит показать в тексте вопроса.

Answer (score 3):

Я конечно не гуру в регулярных выражения, но я думаю, что подобное через регулярки не находится, а если находится, то в результате будет регулярка-монстр...

На мой взгляд, проще разбить одну большую задачу, на 2 подзадачи:

Сначала разделим предложение на слова `\w+`, а затем полученную коллекцию сгруппируем и отфильтруем, что бы получить результат:

```
var res = Regex.Split("A A B B C C C", @"\W+").
GroupBy(r => r, r => r, (key, group) => new {Key=key,Count=group.Count()} ).
Where(r => r.Count==2).ToList();
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `в результате будет регулярка-монстр` что и доказал соседний ответ :) Регулярка хорошо описана, но каждому инструменту свое применение :)

Answer (score 3):

Привожу ответ только для полноты. [Решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1056402/264108), предложенное iluxa1810, безусловно более оптимально.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Rextester {
    public class Program {
        public static void Main(string[] args) {
            Regex re = new Regex(@"\b(\p{L}+)\b" +        // сохранить слово в \1.
                                 @"(?<!\b\1\b.*\b\1\b)" + // проверить, что до начала строки слово встречается только один раз.
                                 @"(?!(.*?\b\1\b){2})" +  // проверить, что до конца строки слово не повторяется больше одного раза.
                                 @"(?=.*?\b\1\b)",        // проверить, что до конца строки слово встречается только один раз.
                                 RegexOptions.Compiled);
            string s = "A B C C B C A D ABCD";
            string pairs = string.Join(", ", from Match m in re.Matches(s) select m.Groups[1].Value);
            Console.WriteLine(pairs);
        }
    }
}
```

Результат:

```
A, B
```

[Демо кода](https://rextester.com/edit/JMR27455).
[Демо регулярного выражения](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cb%28%5cp%7bL%7d%2b%29%5cb%0d%0a%28%3f%3c!%5cb%5c1%5cb.*%5cb%5c1%5cb%29%0d%0a%28%3f!%28%3f%3a.*%3f%5cb%5c1%5cb%29%7b2%7d%29%0d%0a%28%3f%3d.*%3f%5cb%5c1%5cb%29&i=A+B+C+C+B+C+A+D+ABCD&o=x).

Comment: Интересно что ты записал более красиво негативный предпросмотр вперёд, а я - назад :)

Comment: Я это заметил :)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102040/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-andrei-odegov).

Answer (score 1):

```
\b(\w+)\b(?=.*\b\1\b)(?!.*\b\1\b.*\b\1\b)(?<!\b\1\b.+)
```

https://ideone.com/DnBUeA

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    string s = "A B C C B C A D ABCD";

    foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(s, @"\b(\w+)\b(?=.*\b\1\b)(?!.*\b\1\b.*\b\1\b)(?<!\b\1\b.+)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
      Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вариант с атомарной группировкой:

```
\b(\w+)\b(?=(?>.*?\b\1\b)(?!.*\b\1\b))(?<!\b\1\b.+)
```

https://ideone.com/qznDtA

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    string s = "A B C C B C A D ABCD";

    foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(s, @"\b(\w+)\b(?=(?>.*?\b\1\b)(?!.*\b\1\b))(?<!\b\1\b.+)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
      Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
  }
}
```